# Get full path to file from ImagePickerController

Tags: ios, url, path, uiimage

in my app i like to upload an image chosen from the library to a database.
But for the multipart/form-data post request i need the full path to the original media
on the iPhone. I found many topics for creating an image from url and most answers referred to the `CGImageRef`to create an image, but that doesn't really help.

I also found some topics (which where eventually outdated) were people say that its not possible to get the original image through ImagePickerController. I think i have to use ALAssets, but i don't know how to do this ann i didn't find any useful example.

Greets
s4lfish